# How to join three tables in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to join three tables:
sections table:
sectionid
text
formid

questions table:
questionid
question
formid
sectionid

options table:
optionid
option
questionid

I want to fetch all sections where formid=x (for example) and questions related to sectionid and options related to questionid.

```
               $data=Section::with('questions','options')
                            ->where('formId',$formId)
                            ->orderBy('sectionid')
                            ->get()
                            ->toJson();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created two relationships in my Section model. One to joining Section model to Question model and other one to join Section Model to Option model through Question model.

```
class Section extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;
  protected $primaryKey='sectionid';
  public function options(){
      return $this->hasManyThrough(Option::class,Question::class,'sectionid','questionid');

}
public function questions(){
    return $this->hasMany(Question::class,'sectionid');
}
```

}

My Controller:

```
            $data=Section::with('questions','options')
                            ->where('formId',$formId)
                            ->orderBy('sectionid')
                            ->get()
                            ->toJson();
```

It works properly :)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins

### According to what you need:

```
$data = Section::where('formid', x)
            ->join('questions', 'sections.sectionid', '=', 'questions.sectionid')
            ->join('options', 'options.optionid', '=', 'questions.optionid')
            ->select('sections.*', 'questions.question as question', 'options.option as option')
            ->get();
```

### Notes:

1. Do not fetch * from all tables, for most cases you may get ambiguous column error
2. Your coding style does not follow convention which is really bad practice. Following convention helps in many ways.

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution and answered to my question.@Psycho

Comment: your question was about `join` and your answer is nowhere close to that. Anyway, suggesting you to follow laravel docs